# Updating the record in salesforce using REST API in C#

Tags: community

I am running into the following error while updating the record in salesforce custom object
[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"Provided external ID field does not exist or is not accessible: 12"}]

Here is the Code

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RowData);

HttpContent contentCreate = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

string uri = $"{serviceURL}{ApiEndpoint}sobjects/{Object.SalesforceObjectName}/{Object.Id}?_HttpMethod=PATCH";

HttpRequestMessage requestCreate = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
requestCreate.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
requestCreate.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
requestCreate.Content = contentCreate;


HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(requestCreate);
string responseMessage = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    dynamic obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseMessage);
    Console.WriteLine("Record Added successfully " + obj1.Id);
}
else
{
    dynamic obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseMessage);
    Console.WriteLine($"Error Occured while Deleting the record in {Object.SalesforceObjectName} with id = {RowData.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine("Error Message " + obj1[0].message);
    Console.WriteLine("Error Code " + obj1[0].errorCode);

}
```

What am i missing or doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use HttpMethod.Patch instead of HttpMethod.Post, rather than the `_HttpMethod=PATCH` in the URL. This won't fix the problem, but it does make your code a bit clearer.

Second, you've got something wrong with your URL. The External ID URL looks like this:

```
/services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/sObjectName/sObjectField/ExternalIdValue
```

While using a Salesforce ID looks like:

```
/services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/sObjectName/salesforceId
```

This causes me to suspect that `Object.SalesforceObjectName` contains a `/` in it for some reason.

You'll need to review what your data looks like, as you didn't mention what the final URL looks like.

Comment: the URL looks like this 

https://XXXXXX.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/sked__Tag__c/12?_HttpMethod=PATCH

seems to be correct base on template you provided

Comment: I tried little different variant of URL, but that runs into error as well

       https://XXXX.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/sked__Tag__c?_HttpMethod=PATCH

[{"errorCode":"METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET,POST"}]

Comment: @NSS "12" is wrong, a Salesforce ID must be 15 or 18 characters, such as aXX0000000YYYYY or aXX0000000YYYYYZZZ. Second one without an ID is also wrong, that is only for creating a new record (therefore, PATCH is not allowed). If you're trying to use 12 as an External ID, you need to specify the field for which that value is valid.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for pointing about the format of salesforceId, i was using a different id field, thinking that it was an salesforce id. got it working by passing proper salesforceId